# using variables to select axis in r plotly like aes_string

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to provide a variable with the column name to create a `plotly` graph, similar to `ggplot2::aes_string`. Somehow I am stuck...

```
plot_ly(iris, x=~Sepal.Length, y=~Sepal.Width) # works as expected 
plot_ly(iris, x=~'Sepal.Length', y=~'Sepal.Width') # fails since it doesn't use the column
```

I guess this is a pretty easy question, but I just miss the vocabulary to find a solution on stack overflow.

Answer (score 8):

Just figured it out by reading manual (as always)... Using `as.formula` works well.

```
my_x <- 'Sepal.Length'
my_y <- 'Sepal.Width'
plot_ly(iris, x=as.formula(paste0('~', my_x)), y=as.formula(paste0('~', my_y)))
```

But maybe there is a nicer solution?