# How to create a barchart with plotly?

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I'm trying to generate a bar chart with user inputs. I tried using `~` before the inputs but it doesn't work. What I'm seeing is a blank canvas with the axis labels.

[image]

Code

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(tags$h4("Bar Chart")),
  sidebarLayout(
  sidebarPanel(selectInput("input1", label = NULL, choices = names(mtcars)),
               selectInput("input2", label = NULL, choices = names(mtcars))),
  mainPanel(plotlyOutput("bar"))
)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  output$bar <- renderPlotly(
    mtcars %>% 
      plot_ly(
        x = ~input$input1,
        y = ~input$input2,
        
        type = "bar"
      )
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `get()` to convert your input variable to something that plotly can work with. In your case try this:

```
 output$bar <- renderPlotly(
     mtcars %>% 
         plot_ly(
             x = ~get(input$input1),
             y = ~get(input$input2),
             
             type = "bar"
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628311/using-variables-to-select-axis-in-r-plotly-like-aes-string/51628369) a second option would be to make use of `as.formula` like so:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$bar <- renderPlotly(
    mtcars %>% 
      plot_ly(
        x = as.formula(paste0('~', input$input1)),
        y = as.formula(paste0('~', input$input2)),
        
        type = "bar"
      )
  )
}
```